# String builder append method in java queryStr.append(\\%AMPAMP\\$);

Tags: java, stringbuffer

```
queryStr.append("\\\\%AMPAMP\\\\$");
```

after executing this line the querStr removes

one \ from the string and the final result will be:

```
"\%AMPAMP\$"
```

I want it to be:

```
\\\\%AMPAMP\\\\$
```

Comment: Don't see the difference between the two outputs o.o

Comment: `\%AMPAMP\$`

`\%AMPAMP\$`

There is absolutely no difference between these strings.

Comment: please correct what you want, required and output is same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the slash:

```
queryStr.append("\\\\%AMPAMP\\\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
queryStr.append("\\\\\\\\%AMPAMP\\\\\\\\$");
```

A character preceded by a backslash () is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. '\' Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

You can read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html